# OmniSharp not supporting unity anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

So I recently started my final year project in Unity, for the code I use visual studio code, but the problem is that i installed the c# extension from omnisharp and it says that it doesn t support unity anymore or something like that. It doesn t show me any errors, doesn’t complete my code, nothing. What should I do?

Comment: `it says that it doesn t support unity anymore or something like that.` we're going to need the verbatim error here. Copy/paste what you're seeing in the console.

Comment: this is what it says : The C# extension no longer ships with an included Mono & MSBuild Tools
.NET Framework builds of OmniSharp no longer ship with Mono or the MSBuild tooling (See announcement omnisharp-roslyn#2339). To ensure that the C# extension remains usable out of the box for .NET SDK projects, we have changed the default value of omnisharp.useModernNet to true.

If you still need Unity or .NET Framework support, you can set omnisharp.useModernNet to false in your VS Code settings and restart OmniSharp.

See issue #5120 for more details.

Comment: So it *does* show you and error, and it tells you how to fix it: `If you still need Unity [...] support, you can set omnisharp.useModernNet to false in your VS Code settings and restart OmniSharp.` Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

In VS CODE
untick this option:

[image]